# Reading keyboard input from /dev/tty0?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a remote control driver for an embedded system with Linux 3.X. It's using an GUI which reads keyboard input from **/dev/tty0**. Related source codes of this GUI about opening a keyboard device are as follows.

```
static int TTY_Open (const char *unused)
{
    if (geteuid() == 0) /* is a super user, try to open the active console */
        tty_dev = "/dev/tty0";
    else    /* not a super user, so try to open the control terminal */
        tty_dev = "/dev/tty";

    kbd_fd = open(tty_dev, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    if (kbd_fd < 0)
        return -1;

    if (tcgetattr(kbd_fd, &startup_termios) < 0)
        goto err;

    work_termios = startup_termios;

    work_termios.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO  | ISIG);
    work_termios.c_iflag &= ~(ISTRIP | IGNCR | ICRNL | INLCR | IXOFF | IXON);
    work_termios.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
    work_termios.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    work_termios.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    if(tcsetattr(kbd_fd, TCSAFLUSH, &work_termios) < 0)
        goto err;

    /* Put the keyboard into MEDIUMRAW mode.  Despite the name, this
     * is really "mostly raw", with the kernel just folding long
     * scancode sequences (e.g. E0 XX) onto single keycodes.
     */
    ioctl (kbd_fd, KDGKBMODE, &startup_kbdmode);
    if (ioctl(kbd_fd, KDSKBMODE, K_MEDIUMRAW) < 0) 
        goto err;
    return kbd_fd;

err:
    close(kbd_fd);
    kbd_fd = 0;
    return -1;
}
```

My driver was implemented with **Linux input subsystem**. In its interrupt handler, input_report_key is used to report key event.

Then I find it surprising that the GUI can read **both** inputs from an USB keyboard and the remote driver! But the devices corresponding to the keyboard and remote control are /dev/input/eventX. How could it read those inputs from /dev/tty0???

I find it quite confusing and can not get answers from Google. Can someone explain it?

Comment: /dev/tty0 and so on are abstraction on teletype devices. And it’s basically about protocol. Underneath the device drivers are located, such as serial devices. It’s unclear what is the actual design and problem you are trying to fix.